# How to read data as buffer from an audio file as soon as it is added to the file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, file, streaming, http-live-streaming

I have a .wav audio file being recorded live. I just want to read it's data as soon as the data is added to it and send to some other server (or web browser to listen live)

How can I do this in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Create a read stream of your .wav file and pipe it with your write stream.

*This is not an actual working example. This is just to demonstrate how you can achieve it.*

Here, `res` is a write stream!

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file = fs.createReadStream('audio.wav');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  file.on('data', (chunk) => {
    // Send chunk to client
    res.send(chunk); // May be?
  });
});
```

Or, you can use pipe!

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  file.pipe(res);
});
```